# TextToSpeech on textView with multiple LinearLayout?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, text-to-speech

How can I used TextToSpeech on textView with multiple LinearLayout ?

I' trying to add TTS method on emails to read it, so I worked on mail client from open source and started to add the TTS code inside it, so when the button is clicked,the message should be read out loud

this is what I do:

the name of activity class is MessageContainerView

```
unsignedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_unsigned_text);

buttonRead =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);



t1=new TextToSpeech(activity.getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

        }
    }
});

buttonRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String toSpeak = unsignedText.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
});
```

but when I clicked the button,the app stopped

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.fsck.k9.ui.messageview.MessageContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Content area -->
    <com.fsck.k9.view.MessageWebView
        android:id="@+id/message_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <!-- Unsigned content area -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/message_unsigned_container"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/message_unsigned_divider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            >

            <View
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#d55"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/unsigned_text_divider_label"
                android:textColor="#d55"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#d55" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_unsigned_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            tools:text="Unsigned text content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Attachments area -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/attachments_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/attachments"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</com.fsck.k9.ui.messageview.MessageContainerView>
```

Is that because a multiple LinearLayout? so the TTS code doesn't reach to text inside TextView?

Comment: Can you post your error logs?

Answer (score 0):

> **Text to speech** for multiple text one by one.try this

```
 private void speakOut () {
        String que = tvone.getText().toString();
        String op1 = tvtwo.getText().toString();
        String op2 = tvthree.getText().toString();
        String op3 = tvfoure.getText().toString();
        String op4 = tvfive.getText().toString();
        tts.speak(que, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.speak(op1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.speak(op2, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.speak(op3, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.speak(op4, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

    }
```